# RTMPT connection closes with Red5 after some time

Tags: red5

I am using Red5 version 1.0.0(final release) for Java 6 on Windows XP sp3.I am using the installer version downloaded from https://code.google.com/p/red5/. I have a project wherein I am performing live webcam chats between the users. I am using RTMPT (HTTP over RTMP)protocol for that.So I have set up my Red5 server behind the Apache web server.The problem is that everything goes on well for 45-50 seconds and suddenly the RTMPT connection gets closed.I am not using a dedicated rtmpt server,i.e. I have not uncommented the rtmpt bean in the conf files.Rather I have added entries of servlet mappings(for idle,fcs,open etc) in the web.xml of my application. RTMPT is listening on 5080 port.I have tested this with previous versions of Red5 also but the problem is the same.The RTMPT connection closes after some time(within a minute).I had gone through logs but there was found nothing regarding this.Also there was no connection closure due to the inactivity period.Has it something to do with Apache? I am not sure whether server is closing the connection (though I cant find any logs about closing connection) or client closes it.Tried it out with 0.9.0 and 0.9.1 too but nothing to avail.I have heard that there were issues using RTMPT with Red5 on Mac but I am on Windows.Any pointers to this problem? Any help is appreciated.Also here are the error logs that I get on my Apache web server -

[error] (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to red5serverip:5080 (*) failed.

The same log is repeated for four times.

Here are some access logs from Apache too -

"POST /send/IDTK7NOG2PXGB/803 HTTP/1.1" 200 1
"POST /send/IDTK7NOG2PXGB/804 HTTP/1.1" 503 323
"POST /send/YXF4WTFMN8TCM/1391 HTTP/1.1" 200 8285
"POST /send/YXF4WTFMN8TCM/1392 HTTP/1.1" 200 1
"POST /send/YXF4WTFMN8TCM/1393 HTTP/1.1" 200 54
"POST /send/YXF4WTFMN8TCM/1394 HTTP/1.1" 200 1
"POST /send/YXF4WTFMN8TCM/1395 HTTP/1.1" 503 323
"POST /close/IDTK7NOG2PXGB/805 HTTP/1.1" 503 323
"POST /close/YXF4WTFMN8TCM/1396 HTTP/1.1" 503 323

Thanx!

Comment: Tried with dedicated rtmpt server(by uncommenting the rtmpt bean) too.Results the same.Same logs.And connection closed after few seconds.Any ideas people? RTMPT is listening on default port 8088.

Comment: Have a look also @ https://maythesource.com/2016/08/11/reducing-rtmpt-disconnects-on-red5/

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are running out of tcp ports. A tcp connection will remain 4 minutes in the TIME_WAIT state by default, even if it is already closed. When your RTMPT stream uses 5 connections each second, your system will need at least 5*60*4=1200 ports for each connected user.

Often the firewall is limiting the amount of ports available. You can also decrease the keep-alive time of a tcp socket. If you google around with your apache error message you will find enough info to sort this out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am now using ProxyPass with max attribute in apache httpd conf file.On giving value 20 for max the connection between two connected clients lasted for almost an hour and then again the connection got closed.I am still not able to figure out the problem.

Comment: Nothing listed in Apache access/error log files? Otherwise, maybe you can try mod_status to check if Apache is slowly running out of resources. See also http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Monitoring_Apache_with_mod_status

Comment: Or maybe you are suffering from issue 281 "RTMPT random closes", see  http://code.google.com/p/red5/issues/detail?id=281 You can try the workaround from comment 22 (remove sharedObjectService excutor).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.I will try it out and post the results back.For now I have switched back to RTMP.

Comment: by the way, here the apache conf values I am using to let the RTMPT request pass through:  

    MaxRequestsPerChild 0  
    KeepAlive On  
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 0

Answer (score 0):

Your red5 server may be crashed. This occurs when your RAM usage is getting over. In that case  you need to manually start red5 again. If this solved your problem, you need to upgrade your RAM. I am using about 8GB RAM after facing this problem several times. Because red5 was written using JAVA, it lacks memory. FFMPEG is good to use in a low memory. But I don't know how to provide chat using ffmpeg, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The 503 means that the service did not respond; if you are forwarding to red5 via apache, then this means there is a problem there. I would suggest not using the stand alone rtmpt bean; instead use only the servlet and remove apache from the mix to debug the issue.